# Rendering breaks even when condition is true

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render the `<Items>` on the page only where `this.state.sites` is not empty. But instead `can't execute .map on undefined` is thrown. Making a check if the sites are loaded because I am loading them through API. My render looks like:

```
render() {
        let hasSites = this.state.sites.length > 0
        return(
            <Content>
                {!this.state.edit && !this.state.new && !this.state.editSite &&
                    <Form>
                        <button onClick={() => this.setState({new: true})}>New site type</button>
                        {hasSites ? (
                            <Items>
                                {this.state.sites.map((site, index) => (
                                    <Site>
                                        <Header>
                                            <h2>{site.title}</h2>
                                            <p>${site.price}</p>
                                        </Header>
                                        <Body>
                                            <Info>
                                                <p>{site.pax} Pax</p>
                                                <p>{site.rv} ft Max Length</p>
                                            </Info>
                                            {!this.state.addSites &&
                                            <Buttons>
                                                <p onClick={() => this.setState({site: site, index: index, addSites: true})}>Add sites</p>
                                                <p onClick={() => this.setState({site: site, index: index, edit: true})}>Edit</p>
                                                <p onClick={() => this.deleteSiteType(index)}>Delete</p>
                                            </Buttons>
                                            }

                                            {this.state.addSites && this.state.index == index &&
                                            <Buttons>
                                                <input type='number' min='1' max='5' onChange={(e) => this.setState({numberOfNewSites: e.target.value})} />
                                                <p onClick={() => this.addSites()}>Done</p>
                                            </Buttons>
                                            }
                                        </Body>
                                        {!this.state.addSites &&
                                        <SitesList>
                                            {site.sites.map((item, itemIndex) => (
                                                <SiteItem>
                                                    <h2>{item.siteName}</h2>
                                                    <p onClick={() => this.setState({editSite: true, site: site, index: index, siteIndex: itemIndex})}>Edit</p>
                                                    <p onClick={() => this.deleteSite(index, itemIndex)}>Delete</p>
                                                </SiteItem>
                                            ))}
                                        </SitesList>
                                        }
                                    </Site>
                                ))}
                            </Items>
                        ) : ""}

                        <Controls>
                            <Span onClick={() => this.props.previous()}>Previous</Span>

                            <button onClick={(e) => this.submit(e)}>Proceed</button>
                        </Controls>
                    </Form>
                }

                {this.state.edit &&
                    <Edit
                        index={this.state.index}
                        site={this.state.site}
                        editSite={(index, data) => this.editSiteType(index, data)}
                        goBack={() => this.setState({edit: false})}
                    />
                }

                {this.state.editSite &&
                    <EditSite
                        index={this.state.index}
                        site={this.state.site}
                        siteIndex={this.state.siteIndex}
                        editSite={(typeIndex, siteIndex, data) => this.editSite(typeIndex, siteIndex, data)}
                        goBack={() => this.setState({editSite: false})}
                    />
                }

                {this.state.new &&
                    <NewType
                        addSiteType={(data) => this.addSiteType(data)}
                        goBack={() => this.setState({new: false})}
                    />
                }
            </Content>
        )
    }
```

And this is how I am getting the records:

```
 async loadSites() {
        await axios.get("/api/v1/get-site-types/12").then(response => {
            this.setState({sites: response.data});
        })
    }

componentDidMount() {
        this.loadSites();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not coming from `site.sites.map`?  Is your data structure like this: `this.state.sites.sites`?

Comment: try `this.state.sites`  instead of `sites.sites`

Comment: It is from there obviously ... Thank you very much to both of you.